# How to retrieve all translations from yml files in Rails I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml, rails-i18n

I'm guessing that rails stores all the parsed translations yml files in a sort of array/hash.
Is there a way to access this?

For example, if I've a file:

```
en:
  test_string: "testing this"
  warning: "This is just an example
```

Could I do something like, I18n.translations_store[:en][:test_string] ?
I could parse the yml file with YAML::load, but in my case I've splitted the yml files in subfolders for organization, and I'm pretty sure that rails already parsed them all.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You got to call a private method on the backend. This is how you get access:

```
translations = I18n.backend.send(:translations)
translations[:en][:test_string] # => "testing this"
```

Comment: Note that `translations` will be empty if the backend isn't initialized, i.e. if you haven't used it for anything else yet. You will see this if you open up a new console and try to load the translations. You can get around it by doing `I18n.t(:foo); translations = I18n.backend.send(:translations)` (even if you don't have a `foo` translation). I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If the backend isn't initialized yet and the hash is empty, you can initialize it in this way: `I18n.backend.send(:init_translations) unless I18n.backend.initialized?`

Comment: You do not need to use private methods. Just call `I18n.t('.')`

Comment: As an addition to @HenrikN comment, I'd say it can be initialized by calling `I18n.enforce_available_locales!(:fr)` where `:fr` is desirable locale.

Comment: This is a dangerous way to follow. Ie. you won't be able to use this in Rake tasks since I18n hasn't initialized yet. Prefer Eric's answer.

Answer (score 20):

As per 8xx8's comment, a simpler version of:

```
I18n.t(:foo)
I18n.backend.send(:translations)[:en][:test_string]
```

is

```
I18n.t(".")[:test_string]
```

This mitigates having to both preload the translations or specify the locale.

Comment: This was the best solution for me `I18n.t(".")`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `I18n::Fallbacks` unfortunately you can't use `I18n.t('.')` as it just returns the contents current locale (eg. 'en-GB') and nothing from any of the fallback locales (eg 'en'). To get round this you can iterate over the fallbacks and use `deep_merge!` to combine them.

```rb
module I18n
  class << self
    def all
      fallbacks[I18n.locale].reverse.reduce({}) do |translations, fallback|
        translations.deep_merge!(backend.translate(fallback, '.'))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The default I18n backend is I18n::Backend::Simple, which does not expose the translations to you. (I18.backend.translations is a protected method.)

This isn't generally a good idea, but if you really need this info and can't parse the file, you can extend the backend class.

```
class I18n::Backend::Simple
  def translations_store
    translations
  end
end
```

You can then call `I18n.backend.translations_store` to get the parsed translations.  You probably shouldn't rely on this as a long term strategy, but it gets you the information you need right now.

Answer (score 2):

For the people wandering into this old question, there is a solution that does not require calling protected methods. Change your `yml` file as follows:

```
nl: &all

  ... translations here ...

  all:
    <<: *all
```

Now you can simply extract all translations using `I18n.t("all")`, which has the benefit of automatically initializing and reloading the translations in development mode (something which doesn't happen if you call the protected methods.)

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this in a rake task, remember to include the enviroment, or otherwise it will not load your own locales which lives under `config/locales/`

```
require "./config/environment.rb" # Do not forget this

namespace :i18n do
  desc "Import I18n to I18n_active_record"
  task :setup do
    I18n.t(:foo)
    translations = I18n.backend.send(:translations)
  end
end
```