# Rails i18n how to get all keys for a locale file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create translation overrides for customers in my app. I want a list of locale section's key to render for a form.

In Rails I18n, how do I get all keys for a given locale file?

```
en:
  foo:
    bar:
      some_term: "a translation"
      some_other_term: "another translation" 
  baz:
    bizz: "hello"
```

Results would look something like

```
[
  "foo[bar][some_term]",
  "foo[bar][some_other_term]",
  "baz[bizz]"
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823581/how-to-retrieve-all-translations-from-yml-files-in-rails-i18n

Comment: I18n.backend.send(:translations)[:en]
 REF:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282245/list-rails-i18n-strings-with-full-keys