# Extract all available keys from an I18n::Backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

We're migrating our Rails app to using a different I18n backend, so not using the default yml files, or any files at all choosing to download the translations from an internal service.

In our previous implementation we would parse all the keys from the YAML files for the purposes of exposing translations to javascript, so we'd end up with an array of keys like `date.day_names` etc.

However, now we've no YAML in play our current method doesn't work.

How can we extract all the keys we have from our current backend in Rails?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4054527/23915

Comment: TLDR: `I18n.translations` will have all the keys, but only after you've loaded them by calling `t`, so `I18n.t('.'); I18n.translations`, or `I18n.translations[:en]` if you only want one language.

Answer (score 0):

For me in rails 7 `I18n.backend.translations` works.

To find keys, I execute `File.write('i18n.json', JSON.pretty_generate(I18n.backend.translations))`

And open this file in RubyMine and see JSON path in the bottom (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58239189/4284095)